# Renovate custom dependency type

Tags: npm, continuous-integration, package.json, cicd, renovate

We have a renovate bot running for npm with no special configurations.
There we have two sections in our `package.json`

```json
  "projectDependencies": {
    "package-a": "5.1.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "package-b": "~15.2.3",
  }
```

Renovate only updates the dependencies in `dependencies`. In the docs I see possible `depTypes`, but that do not include custom ones.
How can this be achieved?

Comment: You'll have to define a custom manager, for instance with regex: https://docs.renovatebot.com/modules/manager/regex/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try making use of the custom managers using regex: https://docs.renovatebot.com/modules/manager/regex/